# The PhpStorm HTTP client supports PATCH or http verb change for http requests?

Tags: rest, http, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

The http client from phpStorm supports change http verbs in requests? 
More info about this client  - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#run_request . I read the  HTTP Requests Collection from phpStorm but nothing show that support http verb change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does:

[image]

You can use whatever request method you need except for [custom ones](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45735).

Comment: I like to know if is possible run from command line files .http? This in case if I decide to run/write functional tests in this files.

Comment: Not yet, please leave your vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42002